# Dynamically change 'cleanup' config property for Codeception's Doctrine2 module

Tags: functional-testing, codeception

I'm trying to create a functional test suite in which I would like to have some test cases incrementally filling Doctrine repository with some entities. In fact I'm storing images in Postgres database. E.g. in first test case I create and store image. In the second test case which `@depends` on first one I would like to check if extracted image equals to provided in the first. This workflow works well while setting [Doctrine2](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Doctrine2) 'cleanup' setting to `false`. But I don't want to have this option hardcoded since there are other kinds of test cases I would like to execute in `'cleanup' = true` environment. Is it possible to set this option dynamically? Can't find info in docs.

Comment: I think that the easiest solution is to move those tests to a separate testsuite with different options.

Comment: Oh, yeah, @Naktibalda! Simple as that! Aciu labai!